# I want to express that I write about something. Which sentence should I use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, sentence-choice

I want to express that I write about something. It could be history, politics etc.

Which sentence should I use?

> 1. I write articles & blog posts focused on ___
> 2. I write articles & blog posts on ___
> 3. I write articles & blog posts about ___

Comment: All three of them work logically and grammatically.  You could use any one of them.

Comment: I would use on or about. Focused on is OK, but not needed.